# Java lambda loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am still figuring out lambdas and I am wondering about one method.

```
private enum Result
{
    RESULT1,
    RESULT2,
    RESULT3
}
public static Map<String, Result> calculateResults(List<String> list)
{
    Map<String, Result> map = new HashMap<>(list.size());
    List<String> leavings = new ArrayList<>(list);

    map.putAll(leavings.stream().filter(Main::firstFilter).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> Result.RESULT1)));
    leavings.removeAll(map.keySet());

    map.putAll(leavings.stream().filter(Main::secondFilter).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> Result.RESULT2)));
    leavings.removeAll(map.keySet());

    map.putAll(leavings.stream().filter(Main::thirdFilter).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> Result.RESULT3)));
    leavings.removeAll(map.keySet());

    return map;
}
private static boolean firstFilter(String s)
{
    return s.length() == 5;
}
private static boolean secondFilter(String s)
{
    return s.contains("A");
}
private static boolean thirdFilter(String s)
{
    return BlockedStrings.getInstance().contains(s);
}
```

I think it would be super awesome if this could be made in some kind of the loop, but i have got no clue how to code it. Is it possible to assign filter Predicate to the enum variable or do anything else to not make it so repeatable?

Comment: Post the Main filters code, to make easy to understand the code.

Comment: Are you trying to group the list by a property of the elements? If so, take a look at Collectors.groupingBy()

Comment: Are you looking for `leavings.removeIf(Main::firstFilter)`?

Comment: Enums can have constructors, fields and member functions.  Try adding a constructor after the list of enum values with a param for the predicate.  Store the predicate in a field, change the list of values to `RESULT1(Main::firstFilter),` etc. and add a getPredicate function to the enum that returns the predicate stored by the enum's constructor.

Comment: Added methods. RemoveIf looks very usefull in this method, I will use it, though I am looking for a way to make it in the loop, give 3 methods in the array or assign them to enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure, whether I got your intention right, but to me, it looks like you want to do:

```
public static Map<String, Result> calculateResults(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(s -> firstFilter(s)||secondFilter(s)||thirdFilter(s))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> firstFilter(s)? Result.RESULT1:
                              secondFilter(s)? Result.RESULT2: Result.RESULT3));
}
```

This has the disadvantage of evaluating the predicates multiple times. The alternative is to store the evaluation result into temporary objects:

```
public static Map<String, Result> calculateResults(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream().map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(s,
            firstFilter(s)? Result.RESULT1: secondFilter(s)? Result.RESULT2:
            thirdFilter(s)? Result.RESULT3: null))
        .filter(e -> e.getValue()!=null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

Comment: This won't work for rows that match none of the filters.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine your filter methods into a single method that determines the status for each String, you can calculate the results as follows, without the need for the `leavings` list:

```
public static Map<String, Result> calculateResults(List<String> list)
{
    return list.stream().filter(s -> calculateResult(s) != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Main::calculateResult));
}

private static Result calculateResult(String s)
{
    if (s.length() == 5) return Result.RESULT1;
    if (s.contains("A")) return Result.RESULT2;
    if (blockedStrings.contains(s)) return Result.RESULT3;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Holger exactly! That's why you need to filter them out before collecting to the map.

Comment: I see. It’s evaluating `calculateResult` twice. Well, the only alternative is storing intermediate results into objects. If `toMap` allowed `null` value, we could just store and remove `null`s afterwards.

Comment: @Holger Yes. Could map to `Optional<Result>` instead but then you need to filter the map entries afterwards. `list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> Optional.ofNullable(calculateResult(s)))).entrySet()
    .stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get()))` Or bring in Guava.

Comment: Something in that direction. If `null` was allowed, you didn’t need to perform a second, filtering stream operation, but rather you could specify the `HashMap::new` supplier for the `toMap` operation, to ensure mutability and use `collectingAndThen` to perform a `map.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull)` afterwards. But with `Optional`, you have to change the `Map`’s formal type…

Comment: @Holger the final .get() changes back to the proper type.

Comment: Right, your comment’s code changes the formal type from `Map<…,Optional<Result>>` to `Map<…,Result>` by performing a second stream operation, transferring from one map to a new one. I just said, if `null` was allowed, it was possible to do that in-place with only one map, that has already the desired type.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
List<Predicate<String>> predicates = Arrays.asList(
    Main::firstFilter, Main::secondFilter, Main::thirdFilter
);
Result[] results = Result.values();

for (int i = 0; i < predicates.size(); ++i) {
    final Predicate<String> predicate = predicates.get(i);
    final Result result = results[i];
    map.putAll(leavings.stream().filter(predicate)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> result)));
    leavings.removeAll(map.keySet());
}
```

You could also incorporate the filter into the `Result` instances; or you could use a nice `EnumMap<Result, Predicate<String>>` to avoid the parallel array/list iteration.